# Which is the best way to update a hash within a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Is there is a better way to update a value in a hash within a hash?

For example:

```
result_hash = {
   id: queue[:id],
   status:
   {
     added: 0, 
     updated: 0,
     rejected: 0
   }
}
```

I  used one of the two lines below:

```
result_hash[:status][:updated] += 1
result_hash[:status][:added] += 1
```

but read about `hash.update`. When I tried it, only the first value ":added" was updated.

Are there any alternatives or can anyone explain how to use `hash.update` in my case?

Comment: I think your current code is OK; I don't see a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way in which you could use `update` to achieve the same task:

```
result_hash[:status].update({
  added: result_hash[:status][:added] + 1,
  updated: result_hash[:status][:updated] + 1,
})
```

However, I think `update` is not beneficial in this case, and I find your existing code much cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this updates both values. My basic way updates either the :added or the :updated value.

Comment: @Christian Then just remove either the `:added` or the `:updated` line. Anyway, the conclusion remains: you current code contains less duplication and it's a lot clearer.

Comment: I have decided to go for the following solution. I have created a function and passed in the symbol. Thanks again!
result_hash[:status][symbol] += 1